# How to define an icon for my python application in Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: python, icons, desktop-application, process, ubuntu-unity

I have a python (pygtk) application which starts in different modes depending on arguments. I have a bash script for each application mode:

kadro-reader.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/kadro reader
```

kadro-gmail.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/kadro gmail
```

I also have a .desktop launcher for each mode:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Kadro Google Reader
Icon=kadro-reader
Exec=kadro-reader.sh
Categories=Network;
Type=Application
```

Every .desktop launcher defines a different icon. But Unity always shows the same icon for all application modes.

Similar problem with Kupfer: After I have started one mode, Kupfer thinks all other modes are running too.

It seams Unity (BAMF Application Matching Framework) and Kupfer are unable to associate the running processes with the right .desktop launcher.

Ist there a right way how to make clear to debian, which icon my python process wants to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem as follows:

I have installed my generic Kadro application as a python library. For each mode, I create its own python script, which just calls the generic Kadro library with the right paramter.

Now Unity and Kupfer show the right icons.

Answer (score 1):

(Pasting [my response](https://askubuntu.com/a/89478/5014) in askubuntu.com)

I think the problem might not be in the desktop files themselves, but in any of the following:

- `.ui` file: If you're using a user interface file, you might have set the `icon_name` property for the main window. In such a case, I'd say that the icon in the `.desktop` file is not used.
- `pygtk` code: Similarly to the `.ui` file case, you might have set the icon for the main window using `gtk.Window.set_icon_name`, `gtk.Window.set_default_icon_name` or similar.

My advice is to programmatically set the icon for the main window when the application is started using `gtk.Window.set_icon_name` or `gtk.Window.set_default_icon_name` depending on the arguments passed to the application.

Comment: Have used set_icon_from_file(icon_path). But Unity still uses the icon from the (wrong) .desktop file.

Comment: Same with set_icon_name. Does not work. If I delete all my .desktop files, the right icon is used.

Comment: Looking at the [desktop entry specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) I see that `%i` can be used in the `Exec` key to pass the value of the `Icon` key to the program, so this should mean that different icons can be used by the same binary. I think it's worth trying to see if some magic happens.